# HTTP Connection issue

Tags: http, dart, flutter

For days now, I kept getting this error when I load data from the endpoint `Exception has occurred. ClientException (Connection closed before full header was received)`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' show Client;

Client client = Client();

Future<Platoons> fetchMeatifyById(String id) async {
    final response = await client.get('$_baseApi/platoons/$id');

    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      return Platoons(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load platoon');
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the above issue using another Http client for Dart [Dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio), simple but powerful, was able to take control of the app.

Simple HTTP Request

```
class CartApiProvider {
  Dio _dio;

  CartApiProvider(){
    _dio = new Dio();
    _dio.interceptors.add(MeatityHttpInterceptor());      
  }  

 Future<OrderDetailResponse> fetchOrderInfo(String orderNo) async {
    try{
      Response response = await _dio.get('/orders/$orderNo');
      return OrderDetailResponse.fromJson(response.data);
    }catch (error, stacktrace){
      return OrderDetailResponse.withError(HttpErrorHandler.handleError(error));
    }
  }

}
```